# login using aws-amplify library in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify

When i try to implement login functionality using aws-amplify library in react native. At that time we caught the following error like
AuthPiece.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: _awsAmplify.Logger is not a constructor
at ./node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Auth/AuthPiece.js (AuthPiece.js:1:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Auth/Loading.js (Loading.js:1:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Auth/Authenticator.js (Authenticator.js:1:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Auth/index.js (index.js:1:1)

I would be tried following code

*** App.js file***

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import  {withAuthenticator}  from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import { config } from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(config);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

*** package.json ***

```
{
  "name": "shop-with-login",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react-native": "^2.0.6",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.7",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.5",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```